3rd person character controller (Unity) using Kinematic Character Controller. When I hit play in game, character moves on its own without input
I coded a character controller using Kinematic Character Controller from the asset store and when I hit play in Unity, the character starts moving backwards without input. If I give it any input, it moves in that direction indefinitely without stopping. I have included my Player Script, Player Camera Script, and Character Controller script below.
`using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour { [SerializeField] private PlayerCamera _playerCamera; // Reference to PlayerCamera script [SerializeField] private Transform _cameraFollowPoint; // Follow point for the camera [SerializeField] private CharacterController _characterController;

private Vector3 _lookInputVector;

private void Start()
{
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    _playerCamera.SetFollowTransform(_cameraFollowPoint);
}

private void HandleCameraInput()
{
    float mouseUp = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y");
    float mouseRight = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X");

    _lookInputVector = new Vector3(mouseRight, mouseUp, 0f);

    float scrollInput = -Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel");
    _playerCamera.UpdateWithInput(Time.deltaTime, scrollInput, _lookInputVector);
} 

private void HandleCharacterInputs()
{
    PlayerInputs inputs = new PlayerInputs();
    inputs.MoveAxisForward = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    inputs.MoveAxisRight = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    inputs.CameraRotation = _playerCamera.transform.rotation;
    inputs.JumpPressed = Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space);

    _characterController.SetInputs(ref inputs);
}

    private void Update()
    {
        HandleCharacterInputs();
    }

private void LateUpdate()
{
    HandleCameraInput();
}
}

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float _defaultDistance = 6f,
    _minDistance = 3f,
    _maxDistance = 10f,
    _distanceMovementSpeed = 5f,
    _distanceMovementSharpness = 10f,
    _rotationSpeed = 10f,
    _rotationSharpness = 10000f,
    _followSharpness = 10000f,
    _minVerticalAngle = -90f,
    _maxVerticalAngle = 90f,
    _defaultVerticalAngle = 20f;

    private Transform _followTransform;
    private Vector3 _currentFollowPosition, _planarDirection;
    private float _targetVerticalAngle;

    private float _currentDistance, _targetDistance;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _currentDistance = _defaultDistance;
        _targetDistance = _currentDistance;
        _targetVerticalAngle = 0f;
        _planarDirection = Vector3.forward;
    }

    public void SetFollowTransform(Transform t)
    {
        _followTransform = t;
        _currentFollowPosition = t.position;
        _planarDirection = t.forward;
    }

    private void OnValidate()
    {
        _defaultDistance = Mathf.Clamp(_defaultDistance, _minDistance, _maxDistance);
        _defaultVerticalAngle = Mathf.Clamp(_defaultVerticalAngle, _minVerticalAngle, _maxVerticalAngle);
    }

    private void HandleRotationInput(float deltaTime, Vector3 rotationInput, out Quaternion targetRotation)
    {
        Quaternion rotationFromInput = Quaternion.Euler(_followTransform.up * (rotationInput.x * _rotationSpeed));
        _planarDirection = rotationFromInput * _planarDirection;
        Quaternion planarRot = Quaternion.LookRotation(_planarDirection, _followTransform.up);

        _targetVerticalAngle -= rotationInput.y * _rotationSpeed;
        _targetVerticalAngle = Mathf.Clamp(_targetVerticalAngle, _minVerticalAngle, _maxVerticalAngle);
        Quaternion verticalRot = Quaternion.Euler(_targetVerticalAngle, 0, 0);

        targetRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, planarRot * verticalRot, _rotationSharpness * deltaTime);
        transform.rotation = targetRotation;
    }

    private void HandlePosition(float deltaTime, float zoomInput, Quaternion targetRotation)
    {
        _targetDistance += zoomInput * _distanceMovementSpeed;
        _targetDistance = Mathf.Clamp(_targetDistance, _minDistance, _maxDistance);

        _currentFollowPosition = Vector3.Lerp(_currentFollowPosition, _followTransform.position, 1f - Mathf.Exp(-_followSharpness * deltaTime));

        Vector3 targetPosition = _currentFollowPosition - (targetRotation * Vector3.forward * _currentDistance);

        _currentDistance = Mathf.Lerp(_currentDistance, _targetDistance, 1f - Mathf.Exp(-_distanceMovementSharpness * deltaTime));
        transform.position = targetPosition;
    }

    public void UpdateWithInput(float deltaTime, float zoomInput, Vector3 rotationInput)
    {
        if (_followTransform)
        {
            HandleRotationInput(deltaTime, rotationInput, out Quaternion targetRotation);
            HandlePosition(deltaTime, zoomInput, targetRotation);
        }

    }
}


using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using KinematicCharacterController;
using UnityEngine;

public struct PlayerInputs
{
   public float MoveAxisForward;
   public float MoveAxisRight;
   public Quaternion CameraRotation;
   public bool JumpPressed;
   public bool CrouchDown;
   public bool CrouchUp;
}
public struct AICharacterInputs
{
    public Vector3 MoveVector;
    public Vector3 LookVector;
}
public enum BonusOrientationMethod
{
    None,
    TowardsGravity,
    TowardsGroundSlopeAndGravity,
}
public enum OrientationMethod
{
    TowardsCamera,
    TowardsMovement,
}


public class CharacterController : MonoBehaviour, ICharacterController
{
    [SerializeField]
    private KinematicCharacterMotor _motor;

    [SerializeField]
    private Vector3 _gravity = new Vector3(0f, -30f, 0f);
    [SerializeField]
    private float _maxStableMoveSpeed = 10f, _stableMovementSharpness = 15f, _orientationSharpness = 10f;

    [SerializeField]
    private float _jumpSpeed = 10f;
    private Vector3 _moveInputVector;
    private Vector3 _lookInputVector;
    private bool _jumpRequested;

    private void Start()
    {
        _motor.CharacterController = this;
    }

    public void SetInputs(ref PlayerInputs inputs)
    {
        // Clamp input
        Vector3 moveInputVector = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(new Vector3(inputs.MoveAxisRight, 0f, inputs.MoveAxisForward), 1f);

        // Only update _moveInputVector if there is input
        if (moveInputVector.sqrMagnitude > 0f)
        {
            Vector3 cameraPlanarDirection = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(inputs.CameraRotation * Vector3.forward, _motor.CharacterUp).normalized;

            if (cameraPlanarDirection.sqrMagnitude == 0f)
            {
                cameraPlanarDirection = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(inputs.CameraRotation * Vector3.up, _motor.CharacterUp);
            }

            Quaternion cameraPlanarRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(cameraPlanarDirection, _motor.CharacterUp);

            _moveInputVector = cameraPlanarRotation * moveInputVector;
            _lookInputVector = _moveInputVector.normalized;
        }
        else
        {
            // Reset movement vectors if no input
            _moveInputVector = Vector3.zero;
            _lookInputVector = Vector3.zero;
        }


        if (inputs.JumpPressed)
        {
            _jumpRequested = true;
        }
        Debug.Log($"Move Input Vector: {_moveInputVector}");
    }
    public void UpdateVelocity(ref Vector3 currentVelocity, float deltaTime) 
    {
        if (_motor.GroundingStatus.IsStableOnGround)
        {
            float currentVelocityMagnitude = currentVelocity.magnitude;
            Vector3 effectiveGroundNormal = _motor.GroundingStatus.GroundNormal;

            currentVelocity = _motor.GetDirectionTangentToSurface(currentVelocity, effectiveGroundNormal) * currentVelocityMagnitude;

            Vector3 inputRight = Vector3.Cross(_moveInputVector, _motor.CharacterUp);
            Vector3 reorientedInput = Vector3.Cross(effectiveGroundNormal, inputRight).normalized * _moveInputVector.magnitude;

            Vector3 targetMovementVelocity = reorientedInput * _maxStableMoveSpeed;

            currentVelocity = Vector3.Lerp(currentVelocity, targetMovementVelocity, 1f - Mathf.Exp(-_stableMovementSharpness * deltaTime));
        }
        else
        {
            currentVelocity += _gravity * deltaTime;

            if (_motor.GroundingStatus.IsStableOnGround)
            {
                float currentVelocityMagnitude = currentVelocity.magnitude;
                Vector3 effectiveGroundNormal = _motor.GroundingStatus.GroundNormal;

                currentVelocity = _motor.GetDirectionTangentToSurface(currentVelocity, effectiveGroundNormal) * currentVelocityMagnitude;

                Vector3 inputRight = Vector3.Cross(_moveInputVector, _motor.CharacterUp);
                Vector3 reorientedInput = Vector3.Cross(effectiveGroundNormal, inputRight).normalized * _moveInputVector.magnitude;

                Vector3 targetMovementVelocity = reorientedInput * _maxStableMoveSpeed;

                currentVelocity = Vector3.Lerp(currentVelocity, targetMovementVelocity, 1f - Mathf.Exp(-_stableMovementSharpness * deltaTime));
            }
            else
            {
                currentVelocity += _gravity * deltaTime;

                // Apply drag to prevent infinite movement in air
                currentVelocity *= 0.98f; // Adjust drag multiplier as needed
            }
        }
            if (_jumpRequested)
            if (_jumpRequested)
            {
                currentVelocity += (_motor.CharacterUp * _jumpSpeed) - Vector3.Project(currentVelocity, _motor.CharacterUp);
                _jumpRequested = false;
                _motor.ForceUnground();
            }
        Debug.Log($"Current Velocity: {currentVelocity}");

    }
    public void AfterCharacterUpdate(float deltaTime)
    {
    }

    public void BeforeCharacterUpdate(float deltaTime)
    {
    }

    public bool IsColliderValidForCollisions(Collider coll)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void OnDiscreteCollisionDetected(Collider hitCollider)
    {
    }

    public void OnGroundHit(Collider hitCollider, Vector3 hitNormal, Vector3 hitPoint, ref HitStabilityReport hitStabilityReport)
    {
    }

    public void OnMovementHit(Collider hitCollider, Vector3 hitNormal, Vector3 hitPoint, ref HitStabilityReport hitStabilityReport)
    {
    }

    public void PostGroundingUpdate(float deltaTime)
    {
    }

    public void ProcessHitStabilityReport(Collider hitCollider, Vector3 hitNormal, Vector3 hitPoint, Vector3 atCharacterPosition, Quaternion atCharacterRotation, ref HitStabilityReport hitStabilityReport)
    {
    }

    public void UpdateRotation(ref Quaternion currentRotation, float deltaTime)
    {
        if (_lookInputVector.sqrMagnitude > 0f && _orientationSharpness > 0f)
        {
            Vector3 smoothedLookInputDirection = Vector3.Slerp(_motor.CharacterForward, _lookInputVector, 1 - Mathf.Exp(-_orientationSharpness * deltaTime)).normalized;

            currentRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(smoothedLookInputDirection, _motor.CharacterUp);
        }
    }
    
}

